# Is this assignment invalid after explicit destructor call?

Tags: c++

I have come across some code that is intended to replace an object in-place without reallocation of memory:

```
static void move(void* const* src, void** dest) {
   (*reinterpret_cast<T**>(dest))->~T();
   **reinterpret_cast<T**>(dest) = **reinterpret_cast<T* const*>(src);
}
```

This looks like UB to me, since the object is destroyed and then assigned to without being constructed, i.e. it needs to either just copy-assign (the second line only) or explicitly destruct (the first line) followed by placement-new copy construction instead of the assignment.

I only ask because although this seems like a glaring bug to me, it has existed for some time in both [boost::spirit::hold_any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/boost/spirit/home/support/detail/hold_any.hpp) and the original [`cdiggins::any`](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11250/High-Performance-Dynamic-Typing-in-C-using-a-Repla) on which it is based. (I have asked about it on the Boost developers mailing list, but while awaiting responses wish to fix this locally if it is indeed incorrect.)

Comment: where did I put my goggles?

Comment: I know, bit of an eyeful isn't it. I would've simplified, but felt that the context of the original code and its purpose could've been relevant to the answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the `reinterpret_cast`s are well-defined (that is, `dest` really is a pointer to pointer to `T`), the standard defines the end of an object's lifetime as:

> The lifetime of an object of type T ends when:
>
> - if T is a class type with a non-trivial destructor (12.4), the destructor call starts, or
> - the storage which the object occupies is reused or released.

It then gives some restrictions over what can be done with the glvalue `**reinterpret_cast<T**>(dest)`:

> Similarly, [...] after the lifetime of an object has ended and before the storage which the object occupied is reused or released, any glvalue that refers to the original object may be used but only in limited ways. [...] The program has undefined behavior if:
>
> - an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion (4.1) is applied to such a glvalue,
> - **the glvalue is used to access a non-static data member or call a non-static member function of the object**, or
> - the glvalue is implicitly converted (4.10) to a reference to a base class type, or
> - the glvalue is used as the operand of a static_cast (5.2.9) except when the conversion is ultimately to cv char& or cv unsigned char&, or
> - the glvalue is used as the operand of a dynamic_cast (5.2.7) or as the operand of typeid.

Emphasis added.

If the object doesn't end up in this after-life state because it has a trivial destructor, there is no problem. However, for any `T` which is a class type with non-trivial destructor, we know that the assignment operator is considered a member function `operator=` of that class. Calling a non-static member function of the object through this glvalue results in undefined behaviour.

Comment: The `reinterpret_cast`s are indeed valid; `hold_any` is a type-erased value wrapper and ensures type-safety throughout.

(Edit: itchy trigger finger)
I take from your standard quote (thanks) that for a generic implementation with unknown `T`, the assignment cannot be assumed to be valid, and a valid object should be in-place constructed before any of the listed operations can validly take place. If that is the case then a straightforward copy-assignment without the destructor call seems more sensible to me.

Answer (score 0):

> This looks like UB to me, since the object is destroyed and then
>   assigned to without being constructed, i.e. it needs to either just
>   copy-assign (the second line only) or explicitly destruct (the first
>   line) followed by placement-new copy construction instead of the
>   assignment.

There is no need to fix anything, although this code is certainly not safe without further qualification (it's certain to be safe in the context where it's used though).

The object at `dest` is destroyed, and then the memory backing the object at `src` is copied over to where the object at `dest` used to live. End result: you have destroyed one object and placed a shallow clone of another object where the first one used to live.

If you only do the copy assignment the first object will not have been destructed, resulting in resource leaks.

Using placement `new` to populate the memory at `dest` would be an option, but it has very different semantics than the existing code (creates a brand new object instead of making a shallow clone of an existing one). Placement new and using the copy constructor also has different semantics: the object needs to have an accessible copy constructor, and you are no longer in control of what the result will be (the copy constructor does whatever it wants).

Comment: > If you only do the copy assignment the first object will not have been destructed, resulting in resource leaks.

If you copy-assign one object to another, the destination doesn't get destroyed then copy-constructed, so why should it here? This explicit destructor call isn't matched by any subsequent constructor call.

It's easy enough to create a test that results in a copy scenario having one more destruction than construction (though requires [this](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/8268) hold_any bug to be fixed first).

Comment: @boycy: The destination gets destroyed when its lifetime ends, which is not when the copy assignment happens. This code decides unilaterally that the lifetime of the object at `dest` shall end *right now*, and that's why it calls the destructor. Obviously if e.g. you call the destructor on an object with automatic storage duration you will get double destruction when it goes out of scope, but that's your fault. This code "knows" that it's safe to destroy whatever `dest` is going to be passed to it.

Comment: Indeed - and I think that is the bug, though that does require knowledge of the context from which this code is called.

To highlight part of the question, this is "code that is intended to **replace** an object in-place without reallocation of memory"; this code is not replacing the original valid object with another, but leaves it in a potentially-valid state dependent on T.

Comment: @boycy: I believe we are thinking about the same concept, although in that case I don't like the description "leaves it in a potentially valid state". In my book, object == instance and since the destructor is run one object is replaced by another (the caller assumes responsibility that the new object will manage being placed in the old one's shoes). While it seems that you have in mind object == storage location. Since we know nothing about that location you could say that simply the object's state is changed, but it seems wrong to me.

Comment: You're right, that was shabby wording on my part. I should've said the _storage location_ was left in an unknown state.

When you say "since the destructor is run one object is replaced by another (the caller assumes responsibility that the new object will manage being placed in the old one's shoes)." are you implying the assignment operator would construct the object to which it is supposed to be assigning first? That would be a surprising allocation of responsibility. Of course if the assignment operator is a member of T then we've already lost as per @sftrabbit's answer.

Comment: @boycy: No, of course not. I just want to highlight the difference between the assignment operator/copy ctor (which must ensure on their own the object is left in a destructible state) -- and the above technique, which cannot ensure and therefore has to assume quite a lot of things about the state of `*src` and how both `*dest` and `*src` are going to be handled going forward (which includes their storage duration).